# why is default stack size 0

Tags: c, pthreads

i am reading pthreads from https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ and it says

> Default thread stack size varies greatly. The maximum size that can be
>   obtained also varies greatly, and may depend upon the number of
>   threads per node. Both past and present architectures are shown to
>   demonstrate the wide variation in default thread stack size.

then it lists some default values for a couple of processors, but it never says 0 for any processor. So i copy pasted its C program and executed. The relevant part being :

```
   size_t stacksize;     
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_attr_getstacksize (&attr, &stacksize);
   printf("Default stack size = %li\n", stacksize);
```

i get the output :

```
Default stack size = 0
```

Why 0 ?

Comment: I suspect this behavior is actually non-conformant. For example, *The pthread_attr_setstacksize() function shall fail if: [EINVAL] The value of stacksize is less than {PTHREAD_STACK_MIN} or exceeds a system-imposed limit.* This implies to me that "0" is not a valid setting for the attribute.

Comment: @R, from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html : `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN Minimum size in bytes of thread stack storage. Minimum Acceptable Value: 0`. I suspect that's the case here since it's `pthread_init` setting that value, not the user via `pthread_setstacksize`. I would think `init` would set a valid value for use in `pthread_create`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack size in the attribute is the *minimum* stack size, which may well be zero. I suspect in that case, any thread created with that attribute gets a sensible default, 4M for example.

The idea is to leave the attribute stack size alone if you want the default, and set it to something else if you want to force it to a specific minimum.

Comment: 4K is a sensible default? Isn't that really small?

Comment: Well, that was an _example,_ but you're right: I meant 4M. Although you'd be surprised what you can do with 4K of stack space :-) `ulimit -s` on my Ubuntu 11.04 box shows 8M.

Comment: 4k is mildly small, but Linux kernelspace gets by with 4k stack just fine. The only reason you'd need more than 16-32k is if you're using large automatic buffers (e.g. `PATH_MAX` length) or dealing with many nested call frames (e.g. recursion).